# Blender 2.77 won't Render Hair Particles (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, hair

I can't get my hair to render on Blender 2.77a. I'm in experimental, on CPU.
Here is my [Blender file](http://deniscimaf.com/stack/noel.blend)

Comment: Please provide more info about your file and settings. Edit your question and add more relevant data, possibly a screenshot of your settings and render results. Also please provide a as simple as possible file where the problem is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your root thickness at the very bottom was set way too small. [image]
[image]

Try freeing the bake and setting the root thickness to atleast 1.

Comment: Thanks! I know it was a noob question! Thanks for taking the time to answer :)